# Where did English get its perfect tense(s) from?

Tags: english, grammar, history, perfect

Apologies if this is too basic, but I know very little about linguistics and figured this would be a good place to ask.

English seems like it draws from several other langiuages, notably the romance languages like French, where there is not really a perfect tense. That is, there is no tense for "I have been living here for...". Instead one would use prepositions

> J'habite ici **depuis**...

where this would translate literally (whatever that actually means) to

> I live here since...

but actually means

> I've been living here since..

So I'm wondering how, why, and from where English acquired this particular feature. I looked over the Wikipeda page on this but it's more about usage than history.

Comment: This particular use has been called the [_continuative_ perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it).

Comment: Are you interested in the perfect in general ("I have [already] done this", etc), or specifically the version with "have been \_\_\_ing"? (Michaelyus calls it the "continuative" perfect, I'd call it the "progressive" perfect, same thing by different names.)

Comment: Very short answer: for various reasons, Germanic languages lost all tense affixes except past and present. To make up the difference, they did things with auxiliary verbs (_have, be,_ and modals). One of them adopted a completive construction, as we would say it today, _I have that job finished now_, to become _I have finished that job now_, putting together the _have_ and the past participle as a verbal unit. That's the ultimate origin of the English perfect construction.

Comment: @Draconis And I was taught to call it Perfect Continuous tense :)

Comment: @jlawler But in other Germanic languages, as in most of SAE and periphery, the construction is exactly as in French.  English is an outlier.